# Homework question on convergence using the p-adic metric

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

I am self-teaching myself about metric spaces (officially a physics student), and have come across the following question:

I am asked to show that the sequence $215, 2015, 20015, 200015... $converges in the $2$-adic metric on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Now the p-adic metric is that induced by the p-adic norm $||n||=p^{-k}$ where $k$ is the highest power of the prime $p$ that divides $n$ (any motivation as to why this would be a useful metric would also be appreciated...)

Now if I choose an odd integer $x=2m+1<215$, and let the terms of the above sequence be $x_n$, then clearly $x_n-x$ is divisible by $2$ for all $n$, and the 2-adic norm of $||x_n-x||$ tends to $0$ for this sequence. So any such x satisfies the condition for the convergence limit o this series, meaning that the series converges to any odd integer $<215$ in $\mathbb{Z}$? Ad yet I have seen a general proof that the convergence limit of a sequence under any metric is unique!

Note: This question has been edited so some of the initial comments no longer apply.

Comment: @pisco Of course! That was such a silly mistake! Basic maths skills really do fly out of the window when you're tired! If you copy/paste your comment into an answer, I can select it as the accepted answer. Thank you

Comment: Although, I do in fact still have a question regarding the convergence limit. If I choose any odd number x, then the sequence will technically converge to that value. So still the limit is not well defined?

Comment: $x_n -x$ is divisible by $2$ only says $\|x_n - x\| \leq 1/2$. For example $\|x_n - 1\| = 1/2$ for all $n$, so $x_n$ does not converge to $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know much about the p-adic metric but won't this sequence converge to $15$?

Namely, if $a_n$ denotes the number $20\ldots 015$, with $n$ zeros, then $a_n-15= 2\cdot 10^{n+2}= 2^{n+3} 5^{n+2}$, so $\|a_n-15\|=2^{-n-3}$.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answer already gives a proof why $x_n$ converges to $15$, I just address your other question. You write

> Now if I choose an odd integer $x=2m+1<215$, and let the terms of the above sequence be $x_n$, then clearly $x_n-x$ is divisible by 2 for all $n$,

This is correct (and, by the way, would be true for any odd integer $x$; I don't see why you think the restriction $<215$ would be necessary).

> and the 2-adic norm of $||x_n-x||$ tends to 0 for this sequence.

This is not correct, unless $x$ is 15. The $2$-adic norm of $x_n-x$, for an odd integer $x$, is given by $2^{-r}$, if $2^r$ is the highest power of $2$ which divides $x_n-x$. Now you can try out in some examples (use $x=17, 19, 39$) how in these cases, the $2$-adic norm of $x_n-x$ actually goes to 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 respectively. And then, good practice for further studies of $p$-adics, think about why I chose those examples (hint: for these x, what is their $2$-adic distance to 15?)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had thought about it some more and played with the algebra, and realised that it is indeed true that there is a maximum power of 2 dividing the terms of $x_n-x$ for any $x\neq 15$. Since then we can write the terms of the new sequence (whose norm with the p-adic metric we would like to tend to 0 for the sequence to converge to x) as $y_n = 2 \times 2^{n+1} \times 5^{n+1} +a$ for some $a \neq 0$. Say k is the highest power of 2 dividing a then $y_n = 2^k(2^{n+1-k} \times 5^{n+1} +b) = 2^k \times z_n$ for $n+1-k \geq 0$, and clearly all $z_n$ are not divisible by 2.

Comment: So the norm converges to $2^{-k}$ and not 0.

Comment: I think you got it, yes. And that $a$ would just be $x-15$, in my examples $2,4, 24$, giving $k=1,2$ and $3$ respectively.